# AppFabric after installing I can not see the cluster of cache because I do not see commands powershell

Tags: caching, appfabric

After installing AppFabric cache I can not see the cluster of cache because I do not see caching commands in Powershell.

If I run the command Get-Help * cache * I get the following results:

Get-Counter
Invoke-Command
New-PSSession
Remove-Job
New-PSSessionOptio
New-ModuleManifest
Export-FormatData
Get-WmiObject
about_jobs
about_preference_v
about_remote_jobs

none of which is AppFabric cache.

What do I have to do to make the caching commands appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not using the shell link supplied by the AF instalker, you need to import the module many with:

```
Import-Module DistributedCacheAdministration
```

Then, to attach to the cluster, you need to do:

```
Use-CacheCluster
```

Comment: Thank you! I worked ok!
I found the following link that talks about this topic:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677295 (v = azure.10). aspx